# What file to copy in Java Dockerfile command? Hello world examples / file not found

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I've been following some Java Docker hello world tutorials which have Dockerfiles that look like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17
COPY ./out/production/DockerHelloWorld/ /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ["java","HelloWorld"]
```

Above is from [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dockerize-java-app.html#dockerfile) jetbrains example. However, running this with the next steps of the tutorial gives me this error:
`Error response from daemon: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat out/production/DockerHelloWorld/: file does not exist Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream`

Now I have gotten another even simpler tutorial (with just one .java file & one Dockerfile) working from [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/docker-java-example), which used java8 & copied from `./var/www/java`.

From here I have a few questions:

- This copy command seems to be a fairly common step for a Java Dockerfile. Could anyone give an explanation as to what it does? I don't understand how Java builds particularly well.
- Or, in other words, what file is being copied here & how can I find where that file is generated in my project?

If any other info is helpful...

Here's a better look at my directory structure: https://imgur.com/a/02Zw4GN
I was also able to print hello world successfully as just a java17 application. I am using intellij community edition.

Comment: You want to copy your files to the container from this path `./out/production/DockerHelloWorld/`, but such a path does not exist.

Comment: This isn't really a Java question or a Docker question -- it's more of a question about default IntelliJ project structure. It's your job to know where the `.class` file you built went to so you can COPY the structure that contains it.

Comment: Yes @faith I gathered as much as that the path file / path does not exist from the error message. Thanks though.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy is a .class file ([explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-class-file/)) what is being copied over then? I would have kind of expected a jar or some such. Also I've added the intellij tag.

Comment: When you just run `java HelloWorld` it's looking for `HelloWorld.class`; you'd have to run `java -jar something.jar` or set `CLASSPATH=/path/to/something.jar` for it to look for a jar. (A jar is basically just a zip file containing classes, plus a little extra bookkeeping).

Comment: As for what the `COPY` is doing -- that part is a Docker question, not a Java question. It _assumes_ that you have your IDE configured to put class files in `out/production/DockerHelloWorld`, and copies those into the `/tmp` of the Docker container. (Aside: We expect questions to be self-contained enough to be answerable even if links break, so you can safely presume that I've never viewed any screenshots or links; if there's important information within them, make sure it makes it into the text of the question itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per usual, I had done something stupid. Whilst following the [intellij tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/docker-java-example), I copied the docker file & tried running. That failed for two reasons:

1. I needed to swap from `./out/production/DockerHelloWorld' to my project name, ie docker_hello.
2. My project was created using Maven as the build method.
   [image: Project creation]

I was able to get the example working by creating a new project, using the intellij build system as mentioned above & swapping the `./out/production/DockerHelloWorld` to my project name.

..next to find some good maven examples.